# Shiny in R: How to set an input value to NULL after clicking on a button?

Tags: r, shiny

my situation is the following: I have an action button (Next) and some radio buttons. Each time, I click the action button, no radio button should be selected and the input value, e.g. `input$radio` should be reset to NULL (as in the beginning).
My approach in the server-file was as follows:

```
observeEvent(input$Next, {
   updateRadioButtons(session, "choice", label = "", choices = list("A" = 1, "B" = 2, "C" = 3), selected = FALSE)
})
```

This works fine for let's call it the layout. Each time I press the button, the selection from before is not shown anymore. However, the input$choice (input from radio buttons) has still the same value than before. However, I'd like to reset it to NULL since I have some conditional panels following the radio buttons, which are only triggered when input$choice != null.
I very much appreciate any help!

Comment: I suggest you to not use the `input$choice` value, but create a reactive value that take the `input$choice` value. Have a look to the `isolate()`function too.

Comment: while it is possible to have radio buttons with no selection (by passing a length 0 vector to the `selected` argument), once a value I don't think you can clear all selections without refreshing the application (which is probably overkill)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can overwrite the value yourself from the client (browser) side.

There is an inbuild function that is used to assign the various values to the `input` variable, which is called `Shiny.onInputChange`. This is a JavaScript function that is used to send data (things that are selected in the browser) to the R session. This way, you can assign `null` (JavaScript equivalent of the R `NULL`) to the `input` variable you want, thus "resetting" it.

Of course, you need to trigger the client side from the R server, and this is done by a `customMessageHandler`, that is like the counterpart to `onInputChange`. It installs a listener on the client side, which can handle messages you send to the client.

Everything you need to know about those concepts can be found [here](https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/sending-data-from-client-to-server-and-back-using-shiny/).

Below is a short example how to do this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("Next", "Next"),
  radioButtons("choice", label = "", choices = list("A" = 1, "B" = 2, "C" = 3), selected = character(0)),
  textOutput("status"),
  tags$script("
    Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('resetValue', function(variableName) {
      Shiny.onInputChange(variableName, null);
    });
  ")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$status <- renderText({input$choice})

  observeEvent(input$Next, {
    updateRadioButtons(session, "choice", selected = character(0))
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = "resetValue", message = "choice")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @ K. Rohde This looks awesome - thank you very much for the link and especially for your example. I'm wondering do you know how I could use the status as condition in a conditionalPanel?

Comment: @PatrickBalada Can you be more precise? What is the condition you are looking for? I am pretty sure it can be done.

Comment: This was incredibly helpful. We needed to force an observeEvent even though the input value wasn't changing.