# Delete corresponding input element when using removeUI

Tags: r, shiny

**Question**

How do I delete/invalidate the corresponding `input` element, when deleting a control by `removeUI`?

You can see in the `reprex` below that even after the `textInput` is deleted, `input$x` is still 'truthy'. Ideally, I could tell `shiny` that `input$x`  is not valid anymore and any `reactives` relying on `input$x` treat it as if empty.

**Update**

Reading the answers so far, I think I was not clear, what I want to achieve. I really want to know whether one can conceptually 'nullify' `input$x`. In this case I would not have to take any care that something would break down the line.

---

**Reprex**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  div(textInput("x", "Text"), id = "killme"),
  actionButton("del", "Delete"),
  verbatimTextOutput("out")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$out <- renderPrint(req(input$x))
  observeEvent(input$del, removeUI("#killme"))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: `removeUI("#out")`? Or I misunderstand?

Comment: `out` is just there to illustrate that `input$x` is still existing. So I do not care about `output$out` itself, but I would really like to nullify `input$x`.

Comment: I don't know but maybe `session$sendInputMessage("x", NULL)`.

Comment: Nice idea, but did not work unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38347913/shiny-in-r-how-to-set-an-input-value-to-null-after-clicking-on-a-button), shows how to nullify an input. With this the solution becomes:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$script("
    Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('resetValue', function(variableName) {
      Shiny.onInputChange(variableName, null);
    });
  "),
  div(textInput("x", "Text"), id = "killme"),
  actionButton("del", "Delete"),
  verbatimTextOutput("out")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$out <- renderPrint(req(input$x))
  observeEvent(input$del, {
    removeUI("#killme")
    session$sendCustomMessage("resetValue", "x")})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks for the answers though, becuase only thanks to the discussion I could make my question clearer and was able to find the right solution.

---

Short form using `library(shinyjs)`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(debug = TRUE),
  div(textInput("x", "Text"), id = "killme"),
  actionButton("del", "Delete"),
  verbatimTextOutput("out")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$out <- renderPrint(req(input$x))
  observeEvent(input$del, {
    removeUI("#killme")
    runjs('Shiny.onInputChange("x", null)')
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `reactiveValues` for the printed output and assign it to NULL when deleting the div. I dont know if there is a more elegant solution.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  div(textInput("x", "Text"), id = "killme"),
  actionButton("del", "Delete"),
  verbatimTextOutput("out")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  textX <- reactiveValues(x = NULL)

  observe({
    textX$x = input$x
  })

  observeEvent(input$del, {
    textX$x = NULL
    removeUI("#killme")
    })

  output$out <- renderPrint({
    req(textX$x)
    textX$x
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for this workaround. However, I would be really interested whether it is conceptually possible to nullify `input$x`. I will edit my question to make that clearer. Thanks for the proposal anyhow. +1